# Problems with exporting gridview content to Excel, divs and asp:content

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, html, gridview

I have the following problem, up until yesterday my web app worked just fine, I have/had in my content page (**everything worked**):

- query buttons that display their results into the only gridview I have
- an export to excel button that exported the gridview contents to Excel
- email buttons that send the gridview as an email attachment

On my master page I have a div class with an asp:contentplaceholder, then on my content page I call the asp:content with the id of the placeholder on the master page, this section on the content page contained booth the buttons as well as the gridview, however, since my queries display thousands of records, i wanted to make the gridview scrollable in height.

to accomplish this i created another div class bellow the one that contained everything, gave it a name and on the css fixed it size and made scrollable, then i dragged the gridview inside the scrollable asp:content section. the gridview display the query results just fine and it's scrollable just like i wanted, however, when i try to export the gridview contents to excel or send the email with the excel attachment, the excel is empty in both cases, i didn't change the export to excel button, what can be messing up the export?

i'm gonna post the code that's relevant:

excel button

```
protected void Buttonexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=dados.xls");
        StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(sWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered, tem a ver com o botão de exportação para excel*/
}
```

master page section containing both the buttons and the gridview

```
<div class="span8"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="rightcontent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></div><div class="scrollable"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="rightcontentdown" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></div>
```

the content page sections that contain the buttons and gridview, i have a form tag here, could the tag be causing the exporting to not work correctly?

[image: somehow the editor won't let post the entire code]

Comment: Could you please check your gridview in `Buttonexcel_Click` event if it is empty ?

Comment: @suraj singh, how do i check if the gridview is empty?

Comment: if i put the that piece of code i get the error 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

maybe i'm not placing it on the right place or is it missing something?

Comment: I AM SORRY MY MISTAKE ...use this      `int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows.Count);`

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you are calling `Buttonexcel_Click` event before you bind your gridview or your Binding method is inside (!Page.Postback), However try code below here i am populating gridview again in button click event .and then exporting it to excel .

Try this

```
      string attachment = "attachment; filename=xxxx" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                datatable dt = new datatable();
                  // dt =  Your query to get result 

                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {                 
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;//Bind your gridview 
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                        dg.RenderControl(htw);
                        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
```